# will any commulative update change the farm build number

Tags: 2013, administration, installation, update, patching

I am working on SharePoint server 2013, with the following build number, which represents October 2015 CU:-

```
PS C:\Users\staging.user> (get-spfarm).buildversion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
15     0      4763   1000
```

now we have applied 3 security updates yesterday for SP server, here is full details about these 3 updates:-

[link1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3085477)
MS15-116: Description of the security update for Word Automation Services on SharePoint Server 2013: November 10, 2015

[link2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3085567)
MS15-110: Description of the security update for SharePoint Server 2013: October 13, 2015

[link3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3101364)
MS15-116: Description of the security update for Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013: November 10, 2015

now i run the product configuration wizard after installing the above three CU then i check the farm build number again

```
get-spfarm).buildversion
```

which showed me the same build number before applying the above 3 updates which is 4763

now this build number is for October 2015, but i have one updates with KB3101364 which is for November 2015, so should this update change the farm build number to be for November 2015?
now i check the patches from the central administration and this update is installed correctly, but seems it did not chnage the farm build number:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The farm build number does not always get updated with a patch, or even match with the CU build number within Microsoft's KB article. Typically the build number is incremented when Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is updated. None of those patches contains an updated Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, per the file information provided by the KBs.